# Spring AMQP - How to confirm that a message is delivered and Routed successfully?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am looking for a way to delivery a message, and once the message is delivered (and routed) successfully, i need to perform some operations.

I have enabled publisher confirms and returns by:

```
spring.rabbitmq.publisher-confirm-type=correlated
spring.rabbitmq.publisher-returns=true
```

I have configured return and confirm callback on the rabbit template:

```
rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
rabbitTemplate.setReturnCallback((message, replyCode, replyText, exchange, routingKey) -> {
  System.out.println("Message returned");
});
rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback((correlationData, ack, cause) -> {
  System.out.println("confirm"); //correlationData.returnedMessage has the original message
});
```

Here is my publish code:

```
CorrelationData crd = new CorrelationData(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("X-ORDERS", "ORDER_PLACED", request, crd);

crd.getFuture().addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<Confirm>() {
  @Override
  public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
    log.info("Failure received");
  }

  @Override
  public void onSuccess(Confirm confirm) {
    if(confirm.isAck()){
    log.info("Success received");
    doSomethingAfterSuccess();
  }}
});
```

Now, when i publish a message that is unable to route the message :-

1. rabbitTemplate's returnCallBack AND confirmCallBack are also being
   called
2. the onSuccess(..) of the correlationData is still called with
   isAck() = true

So, how can I check if the message is delivered successfully and routed?

EDIT: Found solution. The publish code :

```
CorrelationData crd = new CorrelationData(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("X-ORDERS", "ORDER_PLACED", request, crd);

    crd.getFuture().addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<Confirm>() {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable throwable) {
        log.info("Failure received");
      }

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Confirm confirm) {
        if(confirm.isAck() && crd.getReturnedMessage == null){
        log.info("Success received");
        doSomethingAfterSuccess();
      }}
    });
```

basically changed the condition in onSuccess to "confirm.isAck() && crd.getReturnedMessage == null"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is per the RabbitMQ documentation - you still get a positive ack, but it is guaranteed to be delievered after the return.

So simply check that the `future.returnedMessage` is not `null` in `onSuccess()`.

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.2.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#template-confirms).

> In addition, when both confirms and returns are enabled, the CorrelationData is populated with the returned message. It is guaranteed that this occurs before the future is set with the ack.

Comment: ok, got it. so in the onSuccess callback, I can check if returned message is null along with ack == true. Thanks